# Who is Yasuo fighting in the future?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the 2024 cinematic video from League of Legends, we see a decades-older Yasuo fighting a bunch of soldiers who are ransacking a city or village. Although we only see perhaps a half-dozen soldiers, the arrow fire that we see their leader call upon, particularly near the end, suggests hundreds of archers alone, so these are not some mere local bullies with weird masks.

The masks certainly suggest azakana, but azakana generally seem to be lone threats, not organized into armies. On the other hand, their aesthetics are definitely Ionian, not Noxian or any other force.

Who is Yasuo fighting here? What is their allegiance and what are their goals?